# What are the rules which will make "namah shivay" mantra more effective?

Tags: shiva, shiva-purana

I read chapter 12, 13 and 14 from Shiv Mahapuran(Vaivhav samhita). Shiv gave few rules in discussion with Parvati. Any "matrin" answers below questions i will be grateful.

1. What lamp or oil to use? During chant.
2. In one of the slokas, He mentions to chants in presence of water, can we keep a water vessel and chant? If yes, what vessel material to use? copper or brass?
3. What kind of matt to use?

Comment: It is mentioned in scriptures  thatchants fruitful if done besides fire, lamps, besides water, in a temple, in a cowpen etc. So one can light any lamp (in ghee or oil of your choice). For matt use woolen matt or one made of Kusha.

Comment: Thanks @Rickross. This answers my questions.